# Why don't multiplayer games require you to open router ports anymore?

Tags: networking

It used to be the case that you had to open ports on your router to play some multiplayer games. I haven't had to do that in many years -- pretty much every game works online out of the box. What changed?

Comment: Hm, that's a good question! I remember having to open ports for D2...

Answer (score 25, accepted):

It helps to understand why you need/needed to open ports in the first place.  Once upon a time, every computer on the internet had a unique IP address.  However, with the rise of residential internet (and the decline in IPv4 address space), it became more and more popular to share an IP address amongst multiple devices via a scheme called [network address translation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation) (NAT).

NAT works fine for outbound connections, which accounts for most of the connections an average internet user makes.  However, in order to act as a server, you have to decide which computer that is sharing a public IP will accept a connection on a given port.  This process is called forwarding or opening ports.

Some PC games and many console games (your Halos and your Calls of Duty) still work on a peer-to-peer networking, where one player in the game is the host and must be able to accept the incoming connections from other players.  Thus, *someone* needs to open ports on their router in order for the game to be played.

However, many PC games these days use centralized servers to establish connections between different users.  This means that the players in the games only need to be able to establish outbound connections.  This is no problem, even when NAT is involved, so there's no need to open ports.

There's also a protocol called [universal plug and play](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upnp) or UPnP, which allows routers to automatically understand what ports need to be routed where by communicating with the devices that need the ports.  This is gaining in popularity, but isn't supported by all routers and devices.

**tl;dr:** Games with dedicated servers don't require you to open ports, unless you're hosting the server yourself.

Comment: Also, now we have UPnP.

Comment: There's also [UDP hole punching](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/UDP_hole_punching) with which you can host a server behind *most types of NAT* as long as there is a central (light) server that helps with establishing connections (i.e. not a full game server).

Comment: UPnP is referenced in the answer.  I've not seen many UDP hole punching schemes in use for games, although they don't always make the protocols they use known to us gamers.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer!

I don't know much about networking, so sorry if this is a stupid question. What difference does it make whether you're connected to a centralized or dedicated server vs. directly to another user? If you're on a dedicated server, you still have to receive packets from the server. Shouldn't ports have to be opened for that to work?

Comment: @Archagon, no worries, we're all new to something. :)  It has to do with the way NAT works - as long as someone on your network is initiating the connection, NAT knows how to route the data between the two hosts.  If someone outside your network is starting the connection, NAT doesn't know what to do with that without being told.

Comment: Think about a house full of people with cell phones but sharing just one phone number.  If you call out, the phone company knows to connect you to whoever you called, rather than, say, your roommate.  But if someone calls in, which phone should ring?  You'd have to work some system out.  In phones we might give everyone an extension, and specify which phone should ring for a given extension.  In NAT, "phone extensions" become "ports" that are forwarded.

Comment: So on that note: more than one Xbox playing the same game "online", on the same router, after 2 you'll probably have an Xbox disconnect when one begins hosting a game. So, that is where you still may require port forwarding to stop this, allowing traffic throughput to the main Xbox(having an open NAT) and the others resulting in a strict or moderate NAT). Much simpler with Upnp, however, not always.

Comment: I was told, when they first started making modems, they didn't consider more than one device connected at a time. And as agent86 stated that with the rise of residential internet...Too much too soon. So, the result; port forwarding and port triggering. Followed with UPnP.